# Digging and placing a cut tree or plant in a hole

Tags: word-request

- It is part of my culture to place a cut banana plant in a hole in the ground, which we dig accordingly. It forms part of many religious rituals including marriages.
- Another similar example would be bamboo, which is used for various purposes like a [stationary pull up bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull-up_(exercise)), etc.

Doing the same for a live plant would be called "planting a banana sapling".

**What word may I use for a cut plant or tree or anything else (to make it stand upright)?**

An image for representation:

> [image]
>
> Image Source : https://olcoyote15.wordpress.com

Kindly comment if I couldn't express it in a way that makes it understandable.

Comment: plant cutting: to plant a cutting. Then, use a stick to it to support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cultural actions it may be necessary to explain in many words what the significance of an action is.  So in English, speaking to someone from an Christian English culture I could say "Receive holy communion" and be understood.  But if I was talking to someone from a non christian culture I might have to say "receive a sip of red wine and wafer from the priest, which represents the blood and body of Jesus"

Likewise you can say in English "plant a bamboo pole" or "place a banana plant in a hole"  But the significance might be lost.

The verbs "plant", "place" or "put" can all be used for cut as well as life plants.

Answer (score 2):

If we were placing a ceremonial object like a flagpole or a maypole upright we (in the UK) would probably say we were *erecting* it. The main difference from what your picture shows is that we would not necessarily dig a hole, there might be some other way of keeping it upright.